# Change the call time between callbacks in Audio Core

Tags: ios, audio, time, callback, core-audio

I created custom callback for mixing sounds in real time for a timing music application using ExtAudioFile.

```
OSStatus MyAURenderCallack (
   void                        *inRefCon,
   AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
   const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,
   UInt32                      inBusNumber,
   UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
   AudioBufferList             *ioData
);
```

I need to change the time every single callback is called.

I'm checking how many ticks each new callback is called with ...

```
soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].callTime=mach_absolute_time()-soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].last;
soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].last=mach_absolute_time();
```

In the simulator i get aprox ... 11595773

I need to change this time to be more quick. Anyone know how I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the audio session property kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration to request more frequent audio unit buffer callbacks.